# how to have an inline drawable inside layout xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable

I have some drawable resources that are used only in a single xml layout. I would like to insert them into the specific xml layout (inline) so i could have a better organization of my files and a less overloaded drawable folder

i found this topic:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/complex-xml-resources

but this using an inline drawable as resource for another one... i would like to use it in a layout xml

EXAMPLE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:padding="@dimen/smallMargin">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/code"
        android:text="@string/delete"
 />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

where code.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:width="@dimen/popupButtonSize"
        android:height="@dimen/popupButtonSize"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_population" />

</layer-list>
```

code is only used in that specific layout, is there any way to make it inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be the issue? If you follow the guide it works without a problem:

1. Add `xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"` to root node
2. Replace `android:drawableTop="@drawable/code"` attribute with `aapt:attr` child

Final XML will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/smallMargin">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/delete">

        <aapt:attr name="android:drawableTop">
            <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

                <item
                    android:width="@dimen/popupButtonSize"
                    android:height="@dimen/popupButtonSize"
                    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_population" />

            </layer-list>
        </aapt:attr>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```